# Don't want to overstay my Schengen 90 days

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, cruising

[image]

For this cruise itinerary would Dec 9 be the last day counted for my 90 days?  Important question, because the 9th is day 88!

Comment: This question will need improvement, as neither the title nor the body text (without the externally linked image that will inevitably disappear) contains anything useful for future viewers.

Comment: When will you enter the schengen area? 
Are you leaving the schengen area on the 9th of december?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that you'd be stamped out at Lisbon and back in at Ponta Delgada, in which case December 8th would be day 87, but it's unlikely, and it won't affect the answer to your question in any event.  Staying 87 or 88 days only makes a difference to you if you intend to spend three days in the Schengen area before early March.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since *Ponta Delgada, Azores, Portugal* is the last place where a passport exit control can occur and an exit stamp be placed.

Azores, Madeira, and the Canary Islands are part of the Schengen Area.

The overseas departments and territories of France, the Netherlands, Norway, and Denmark (such as in the Caribbean, Svalbard, Faroe Islands, Greenland) are **not** part of the Schengen Area.